# Sending a secure (SSL) web socket request using Python and the websocket-client library and hoping to better understand what's happening

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, request, request-headers

I'm trying to build and send a websocket request using Python and the websocket-client library, but I want to understand why I keep getting either a 400 or 502 code, or the connection times out, when trying different variations of the URL and header values.

For one thing, I'm kinda new to web socket requests, and am not exactly any kind of expert in diagnosing regular old HTTP requests for that matter.

Luckily there is debug information available that allows me to view the request as plain text.

Honestly, at this point, I'm pretty much just tossing darts at a board at random, tweaking the websocket URL and the header values, but would really like to be able to know how to approach this systematically.

For some wider context, here's the github repo that I'm trying to adapt (basically, I'm trying to abstract away the most fundamental parts of the code to understand how it works and get the simplest possible version working - without any of the bells and whistles).

https://github.com/odsum/TinyChatBot

### This is an example request sent to a general/generic tinychat URL (with standard SLL port 443)

```
cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie hash=79d26a617642869dcbf218289211945c for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie pass=925c6a6f825421f84bd0e68e4fdd404b for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie tcuid=rB8UtFxM4FGx2ka1BMmrAg== for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie user=cooldudeusername for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImhUeU1cL3NXMzJVQXRsTVh6a1NkdGFBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IndiN1ZYbEJQOTZHYXpjUVFcL25SU1BPcTV6Y2tKbVRUYTV1NHJ5cWxXeXNRMGIwNnl0WDNEeU9wZXUrdEdTTWkwd0xNK09VcFhDRnpsd3dXTE1JY0l1UT09IiwibWFjIjoiYjdlZmIxNWNhNTJkYzczOTYzYTk2Nzg5MjQyODhhZGE2NTIxZDQ5Nzk3NWRhOTg5NGExNDkwM2JiYjk2NjFkNyJ9 for tinychat.com/>, <Cookie remember_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc=eyJpdiI6Ik1rbzIxWGRDdTBrN1huMFp1RzZleXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibHI3NTROcFc4V3pYSk90K2RValZwdjRvSml2K1wvdVhNSHd5SDZKWFdZaEZ6Qk4wVHFTa1EybzIySXQ4RzN0R3R5VTJqMGR2QlUySkVxWG9sWmNBUTdreTF0NTdVV0hcLzdTa1dIbHVsQVU5d1wvYVhmZFRhRTkzaXFqaFBzaWFET04iLCJtYWMiOiJlNmUzOTYzNjA0YWU5YTEzOTlkZTdhZTc2NjhlYzQ2OWQ5MGJhZWI2OGQ4MTUzNjNiNjQwYTEyZmQ3MmY1NTkxIn0%3D for tinychat.com/>, <Cookie sm_dapi_session=1 for tinychat.com/>, <Cookie tcsession=3de8c7d90f323fcc4753d764722d6582649f34f6 for tinychat.com/>]>

--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: wss.tinychat.com:443
Origin: https://tinychat.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XlfPqPAzStqTbVg2Y4lxBQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent
Connection
Cache-Control
Accept
Accept-Language
Accept-Encoding
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions

-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2019 22:33:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 138
Connection: keep-alive
-----------------------
```

### This next example here uses a dynamically generated WSS URL that has a unique subdomain and port (which is fetched earlier in the code).

```
cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie hash=af9b5641e1fffed6c3f7ca8b74c29b54 for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie pass=414fc913a67cf4fdc59f93f117e98e2c for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie tcuid=rB8UtFxM4Ymx2ka1BMtqAg== for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie user=cooldudeusername for .tinychat.com/>, <Cookie XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im9RckxrVDFmbllEaE5QeXlKUVBDZXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQUFwRkdwVXE5NFwvYk43Z0NnY3BJbnlJZzRWQWZDMEZHNFgrbG1nMUJOOG84dFwvYWk0N3dXNDcya3hyaXBcLzdSODRCOGpUbnVoNHdNRGJ2eDhTRitwZXc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjA2YjFjYmY3OGI4MGE5MTljNjI4MmE2ZWJkYzI0YTdkZWQ2N2MxOWNkNTM4ODZmYTg1Mjc4ZjViNTlmNjU3NTAifQ%3D%3D for tinychat.com/>, <Cookie remember_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc=eyJpdiI6IloyRDluMHV6dGlJY3dUeHB5VFNnaFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieXRLUWhXY2NRcjNHOTdoN1lQMXVIOW9zZUpcL1ZaWXg2XC9vZ0x3K3BjUnRtcEh6ZFNzNEh1SUgrR1FId0hiTTB6ZEtkMThUWFhGcXlYUko5T0xXYU5wUUYrMHBcL0NWTWtUXC9nMVloNWR0NDZqU1B1UlI1UU9Ic2dCNHExTmUyVG1XIiwibWFjIjoiMmEyZTc0OTg3ZDBhMzUyOTU0NzAyZmY5MzM2ZTQ5MDIxOTFhYjJjOTY1NWZlOTJhODFkZmI4ODk0ZGMwN2NiZCJ9 for tinychat.com/>, <Cookie sm_dapi_session=1 for tinychat.com/>, <Cookie tcsession=ad801ba583d0ce703a8d1cf313fe75f86a036ea3 for tinychat.com/>]>

--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: wss0703.tinychat.com:27857
Origin: https://tinychat.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ha4h+9adTDWAitNtimMy7Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent
Connection
Cache-Control
Accept
Accept-Language
Accept-Encoding
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions

-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
-----------------------
```

I have tried other variations, but there's no point in pasting code here showing each and every other scenario, because there are a potentially infinite number of possibilities.

When it comes to tweaking the headers (whether adding other ones, removing some that are there, or changing the values for those already in the mix), I just don't know how to make an informed decision in this regard.

(By the way, this is my first Stack Overflow post... kind of exciting, not gonna lie).

Comment: Hi, and Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is nice that you are doing what you are doing and that you use SO to find help. But, what is your question? ;)

Comment: I don't know if questions have to be especially specific or not... Mine is actually kind of general. What I'd _really_ like, ideally, is some guidance towards understanding the overall procedure so that I can reason my way towards a solution (the whole teach a person to fish rather than just tossing them a fish kinda thing). I just have no idea how to even start modifying the variables that are going into my request (and by that I mean both the WSS URL, and the header parameters and values being sent with the request).

Comment: I hope that clarifies things..?

I mean I get the 400 code (bad request) when I use the dynamically generated URL... So I don't see what I'm doing wrong. But it could feasibly be just about anything here. Is my URL not formatted correctly? Are my header values totally nonsensical? I mean, I have very little actual understanding of precisely _why_ those particular parameters are explicitly specified in the Github repo's code I'm adapting from.

Comment: I think you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Those should help you write better questions.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely check out those links.

I guess I can comfortably assume that you see nothing at all wrong with the headers I'm currently using or the way the WSS URL is formatted, then, correct? The error is something more complex then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got it working.

As it turns out, most of those header values were not only completely unnecessary, but some perhaps even erroneous, inaccurate, or otherwise incorrect.

Also, cookies were entirely unnecessary as well.

To anyone else who might come across this - A brief lesson on cookies in their most fundamental nature:

Cookies can, and apparently often do, consist merely of a single token string that was dynamically generated at the beginning of the session, but must be sent with each subsequent request.

Thus, the token can be held in memory in a simple variable rather than using a request library's cookies explicitly.

There's some more good information on cookies here: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/01/08/web-security-session-cookies/